# Do puranas mention any sages/yogis other than Sage Dadhichi who showed A Universal form?

Tags: scripture, puranas, rishi, yogi, vishwaroop

In Shiva Purana, We come Across Sage Dadhichi, Who is said to have showed A universal form.

Shiva purana Section 2.2 - Rudra-saṃhitā (2): Satī-khaṇḍa Ch 39

[image]
[image]

Do puranas similarly mention any other Yogis/ Sages or mortals displaying a universal form?